# AWS dynamoDB, Android updateItem not working

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update an element in a dynamodb table but it never updates I've done some digging and found that in the updateItem function it doesn't think that the anything in the document has changed any adivice on how fix this  (also I am able to get element no problem)

```
            Document builder = table.getMemoById(Room);
            builder.commit();
            builder.put("room_status","clean");
            Document tmp = table.curr_table.updateItem(builder,
            new Primitive(Room),
            new UpdateItemOperationConfig().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.UPDATED_NEW));

            Log.d(TAG, tmp.toString());
```

after using the debugger I found that the issue is in Primitive.java where the last line and this.value is compared to this.value but needs to be other.value the file is read only any suggestion on how to fix this

```java
 public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Primitive other = (Primitive) obj;
        return Objects.equal(this.type, other.type) && Objects.equal(this.value, this.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out if you use the current version of the library 2.9.2 this is fixed I was using a much older version